# Javascript code cached in browser

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a below inline Javascript code in my aspx page of asp.net web application.

```
 function Confirm_Popup(dealid) {
 var bVal
 bVal = confirm("Are you sure you want to assign the same deal again?");
 if (!bVal)
    window.location.href = "page.aspx?id=" + id;
else
    window.location.href = "page1.aspx?id=" + id; 
}
```

I am calling the code from code behind file like below.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me.Page, Me.GetType(), "showalert", "Confirm_Popup('" & Id & "');", True)
```

Step 1: Open the the page link for the first time.

Step 2: Open the same link again in new tab.

Issue is I am getting confirm Pop up in Step 1 but Step 2 is not giving pop up.
Requirement is to display pop up in step 1&2. It seems like code is cached by browser.

Kindly help.

Comment: are you sure the code is being cached? upon clearing the cache and running again, is it working as expected?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors? Can you confirm that the JS is *definitely* being injected? I am not sure of the scope of `ClientScriptManager` but it could be possible the second call in a new tab is deemed a duplicate given the page type/key are identical (I wouldn't have thought so though).

Comment: Sorry... Problem is not related to caching. Issue with my existing code which is fixed now. Thanks for your time.